# How to create a wave effect like this using drawable xml file using layer list

Tags: android, layout

I want to set it as background so basically i need an xml code using layer list or something.Can some one help me with it please.

[image: i want the wave view as shown in the image]

i have something like this with me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:height="50dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:top="-0dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:height="20dp"
    android:bottom="30dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: sir i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the image file into `res/drawable`
2. In your `XML` layout root view, add

`android:background="@drawable/file_name_without_extension"`

Comment: bro i need to know the code for creating xml (using layerlist)

Comment: Be more precise. You can either use `SVG`s or stack views inside a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: that worked for me thanks brother